# App crash in release build for enabling proguard when using GreenDao

Tags: android, proguard, greendao, greendao3

I am using GreenDao in my project, when I build the application in release mode then the app crashes. If I disable proguard (`minifyEnabled false`) in gradle then it's running perfectly. I have used the following rules in proguard.

```
### greenDAO 3
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao {
public static java.lang.String TABLENAME;
}
-keep class **$Properties

# If you do not use SQLCipher:
-dontwarn org.greenrobot.greendao.database.**
# If you do not use RxJava:
-dontwarn rx.**
```

**The error log is as follows:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.greenrobot.greendao.DaoException: Could not init DAOConfig
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3229)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Do you have any idea why this error occurs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue by preserving all of my entity (data) classes.

```
# Preserve all entity (data) classes
-keep class com.xxx.xxx.entity.* {*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code [snippet](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/proguard/)

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
   @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# Only required if you use AsyncExecutor
-keepclassmembers class * extends 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
<init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}
```